# How to use a 2D array of pointers in C to store strings?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Lets assume that I have a file, that contains the following strings:

```
option0 value0
option1 value1
....... ......
optionX valueX
```

I am trying to make a C program to read the file. 
I decided to create a 2D array of pointers to strings and store all options in the pointee(s) of the first row and all values in the pointee(s) of the second row. This way:

```
pointer[0][0] should point to option0
pointer[1][0] should point to value0
pointer[0][1] should point to option1
pointer[1][1] should point to value1
```

It seems that the program reads the file successfully, but I can not access the strings to print them out. 
Here is a stripped down version of the code, which causes the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

#define BUFF 1024

FILE *fd;
int i = 0;
char buff[BUFF];
char *options [2][20];

fd = fopen("foo.txt", "r");

while (!feof(fd)) {

if (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fd) != NULL) {

        (options[0][i] = malloc(sizeof (char) * 512)
        (options[1][i] = malloc(sizeof (char) * 512)

                sscanf(buff, "%s %s", options[0][i], options[1][i]);
                i++;

}
}

while (i >= 0) {

printf ("Option %i is %s its value is %s", i, *option[0][i], *option[1][i]);

i--;
}
fclose(fd);
return 0;
}
```

I played a few days with that, but I can not seem to make it work. I checked various Stackoverflow questions and other online resources, but even experimenting did not help me figure out that.

What I want to know is:
Are the strings stored properly with malloc and sscanf? If 'no', why?
Why am I not able to print the string with the printf statement? How to fix that?

Please be aware that the code shown is only for testing purposes, so I am aware that there is no error checking, etc..

Comment: Don't use `feof` to control loop. `while(!feof(fd))` is always wrong

Comment: Don't use 2D arrays in C. Use `arr[i*width+j]` when you need them. BTW, you want an [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Comment: @ameyCU Thanks for the suggestion, I will make sure to adjust that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch what is the problem with 2D arrays in C?

Comment: Their only use case is for fixed dimension 2D arrays in practice (which does not fit here: the file could have more than 20 lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dereferencing the pointers when giving them to `printf`. It expects `char*`, not `char` for `%s`.

```
printf ("Option %i is %s its value is %s", i, *option[0][i], *option[1][i]);
```

This should be

```
printf ("Option %i is %s its value is %s", i, option[0][i], option[1][i]);
```

Another issue is you have to decrement `i` before printing in the while loop. You increment it after each memory allocation, so in the end it points past the last element. Move the `i--;` to be the first inside the while loop.

Also `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you don't need that in calculating sizes for `malloc()`.

Please also adjust your compiler's warnings to a higher level. For example gcc with `-Wall` will say:

> warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]

Comment: I adjusted the printf statement as suggested, but I still get "Segmentation fault" errors.

Comment: @zilog Added another issue which probably causes this crash.

Comment: Thanks! I also discovered that `while (i >= 0)` should be `while (i > 0)`. I do not get any Warnings now also.

Comment: Am i wrong in that decrementing i should come before the printf? @zilog

Answer (score 0):

1) `i--` has to come before the `printf`

2) As in the answer of Sami, dont dereference the pointers in `printf`

```
while (0 <=-- i)
    printf ("Option %i is %s its value is %s", i, option[0][i], option[1][i]);
```